# How to listen to a JFrame window closing from its parent JFrame in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

My program launches a JFrame from an already running parent JFrame.  The second JFrame has autonomy from the first except for one condition - I require a button in the parent JFrame to be disabled when (and only when) the second JFrame is open to prevent additional JFrames being launched.

So my question is, how can I listen to the second JFrame's 'existence' **from the parent JFrame** in order to manipulate whether my button is active or not?

My parent JFrame launches the secondary JFrame as follows:

```
try { 
    second_frame Jframe = new second_frame(variable);
    Jframe.second_frame.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

followed by:

```
btn_open.setEnabled(false);
```

to disable the button once the second JFrame has been launched.

So how can I now listen to the second JFrame's window status from the first JFrame in order to re-enable the **btn_open** button.

Comment: You shouldn't use multiple JFrames, but you can achieve this with adding a [Window Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the second JFrame - No need for anything in the first frame.

Comment: Yes thank you, I've been informed that I shouldn't use multiple JFrames previously, unfortunately, this is how the program is written.  I know of Window Listeners, but I don't know how to use one to inform the buttons status in the parent JFrame.

Comment: Pass a reference of the button to the listener...? Actually, I have done similar things with MenuItem/JDialog. Instead of disabling the item, I pop the existing dialog to front when selected. Thats more useful than disabling the component, IMO.

Comment: The second window requires autonomy unfortunately, it must be able to be used in parallel with the first window and therefore the second window requires visibility and usability.  So I can't hide it or close the parent when the secondary is launched which are nice and easy solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to add a [`WindowListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) to the second frame. You can call `button.setEnabled()` every time the frame closes or opens. (There are implemented methods for that)

Here is an example:

```
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Example {

    JButton button = new JButton("Open");

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        new Example();

    }

    public Example() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                new secondFrame();

            }
        });

        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        frame.getContentPane().add(button);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    class secondFrame extends JFrame implements WindowListener {

        public secondFrame() {

            setSize(200, 200);
            setVisible(true);

            addWindowListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {

            button.setEnabled(true);

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {

        }

        @Override
        public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {

            button.setEnabled(false);

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for this.  It was almost exactly what I wanted, the only change I had to make, was that I had to pass the button as an argument when the second JFrame was launched, as it is in a separate class.  Otherwise it works exactly as intended.